# Linq wild card search with Sql Functions.Pat Index for multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq

If I wanted to pass wild cards against a single column, the results are as expected using the PatIndex function:

```
 (SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%Precision", rle.ProblemDescription) > 0)
```

Now if I wanted to scan for multiple columns, would the following be an inefficient way to execute the query?

```
 (SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%Precision", rle.ProblemDescription) > 0)
 &&
 (SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%Precision", rle.RunDescription) > 0)
 &&
 (SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%Precision", rle.ProblemCodes) > 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think that's more inefficient than it needs to be. However, you presumably want to match on *any* column, so using `||` instead of `&&` makes more sense?